# jQuery, responsive menu won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a responsive menu for my website.

```
if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches){
- my code -
}
```

I use this code above to detect the size of the window, but there is one problem and that is when i'm resizing it, i have to update the site in order to make it to work again, how can i do this without updating it?

Comment: You would need to watch for resizing and trigger it after each resize as well. Any reason you aren't going with CSS and media queries?

Comment: He probably wants to run a JS function when the window is below 767px wide

Comment: Jacob Gray is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(window).resize()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
    // your code
  }
});
```

Or use CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { /* your css */ }
```

Comment: It kind of works, do you know how to make the slideToggle(); effect to work? Because now it slides up and down constantly.

Comment: Try using `stop()` before `slideToggle()` (i.e $(element).stop().slideToggle()) or wrap it in `if (!$(element).is(':animated')) { // use slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
       if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches){
       // my code 
       }
 });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ebqhdox/)
Another way to do the same thing would be like this:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
          if($(window).width()<=767){
               // my code 
          }
 });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ebqhdox/1/)